# A message sent to me in spell cards

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, cards

My brother went missing a few days ago. No one has seen him since then. The day he went missing, I saw the following arrays of my new Dungeons and Dragons spell cards. I didn’t think much of it then, but now I think it’s a message to me. It might tell me where he is.

The arrays are, from top to bottom:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also decided to add a picture of the card with all the class symbols on it, in case it becomes important.

[image]

Note:

> 1. The puzzle is contained entirely within the information on the cards. No D&D knowledge is required (though it may be minimally helpful.) Any required information is provided.
> 2. There is really only one main puzzle going on here. The rest is to point you towards it.
> 3. Most likely, you’re looking for the name of a place.
> 4. There is no information contained within the spell effect section (the biggest section of text)

That’s all for now. Good luck, and happy puzzling!

#### Hint 1:

> Does a part of two of the arrays of faceup cards seem... similar?

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer

> If you take the first letters of the each spell in the first set and interpret the upside down 7 as an L, you get LEVELS IN 4. Taking the levels of each spell in set 4 (assuming cantrips are 0) gives 240150180. Now using the A = 1, B = 2 etc. code, you get XOR, which is a kind of logic gate. I’m not sure how to use it here though.

Comment: XOR can also be a type of encryption. Also, can you write Partial Answer before your spoiler?